# Change Pinterest feeds to English

Tags: pinterest

It seems all my Pinterest feeds are in foreign languages, mostly Spanish. How can I translate them or change the feeds to English only?

Comment: did you try to change your language settings to other language and then back to English?

Answer (score 1):

- click on the three dots in the upper right corner and choose "editar ajustes"
- in the left margin, select "configuracion de la cuenta"
- click the "idioma" dropdown and select the preferred English dialect
- click "listo" in the upper-right to save changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have any language setting in my dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the text and an option to translate will pop up. I find a lot of Italian recipes that I have to do this to to understand.